# In Sabre, Terminal PCC booking api failure due to error

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, sabre, sabredav

In sabre Terminal PCC, we tried to book an itinerary but sometimes it works and sometimes it fails due to this error ( "SOAP-ENV:Envelope" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>").

Could you please tell us what errors are in the request payload because the same type of request payload works fine sometimes and fails other times?

Error Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<detail>
   <StackTrace>javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line 1 of document  : The element type "SOAP-ENV:Envelope" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "&lt;/SOAP-ENV:Envelope&gt;". Nested exception: The element type "SOAP-ENV:Envelope" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "&lt;/SOAP-ENV:Envelope&gt;".</StackTrace>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response on webservices.support.sabre.com.

**1st response mail from sabre:**

> Yes, I tested with your shared failing RQ, it's working with some
> unimportant errors due to it being used in the CERT environment, logs
> attached. How many instances of this error response have you seen?

**To Sabre:**

> We went through the production booking API logs and nothing
> failed like this error, but it failed once in a production environment
> in Terminal PCC alone.
>
> Note: The Cert Test did not face these types of errors.
>
> Please let us know what to do in the future if the same error occurs.

**2nd response mail from sabre:**

> Since this is a rare occurrence, our advice is to retry the RQ if you
> ever get this error again. Let us know if you come across this again.

As suggested by the Sabre support team, it won't reproduce again.